# How do I stop a delay-loaded DLL from throwing a "missing from your computer" system error?

Tags: c, winapi, dll, plugins, teamspeak

I set up delay loading in my plugin yesterday:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma warning (disable : 4100)  /* Disable Unreferenced parameter warning */
#include <windows.h>
#include <delayimp.h>
#endif

...

// Configuration Properties / Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies: ./lib/libcurl.lib;./lib/libxml2.lib;./lib/iconv.lib;./lib/zlib1.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
// Configuration Properties / Linker / Input /Delay Loaded Dlls: libcurl;libxml2;iconv;zlib1;%(DelayLoadDLLs)

#include "curl.h"
#include "HTMLparser.h"
#include "xpath.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl")
#pragma comment(lib, "iconv")
#pragma comment(lib, "libxml2")
#pragma comment(lib, "zlib1")
#endif
```

[[1](https://github.com/NobleUplift/TeamSpeak3WebsitePreview/blob/master/ts3websitepreview/plugin.c#L4)]

And I'm initializing the DLLs on plugin load:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    SetDllDirectory(L"./plugins/ts3websitepreview/");
    if (FAILED(__HrLoadAllImportsForDll("libcurl.dll"))) {
        ts3Functions.logMessage("Could not load curl.", LogLevel_ERROR, "Plugin", 0);
        return 1;
    }
    if (FAILED(__HrLoadAllImportsForDll("libxml2.dll"))) {
        ts3Functions.logMessage("Could not load libxml.", LogLevel_ERROR, "Plugin", 0);
        return 1;
    }
    if (FAILED(__HrLoadAllImportsForDll("zlib1.dll"))) {
        ts3Functions.logMessage("Could not load zlib1.", LogLevel_ERROR, "Plugin", 0);
        return 1;
    }
    if (FAILED(__HrLoadAllImportsForDll("iconv.dll"))) {
        ts3Functions.logMessage("Could not load iconv.", LogLevel_ERROR, "Plugin", 0);
        return 1;
    }
#endif
```

[[2](https://github.com/NobleUplift/TeamSpeak3WebsitePreview/blob/master/ts3websitepreview/plugin.c#L140)]

Here is my build log after adding the pragma statements:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ts3websitepreview, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2016-06-15 06:35:23 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\ts3websitepreview.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  plugin.c
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Link:
1>     Creating library .\ts3websitepreview.lib and object .\ts3websitepreview.exp
1>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:libcurl ignored; no imports found from libcurl
1>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:libxml2 ignored; no imports found from libxml2
1>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:iconv ignored; no imports found from iconv
1>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:zlib1 ignored; no imports found from zlib1
1>Manifest:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LinkEmbedManifest:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  ts3websitepreview.vcxproj -> .\ts3websitepreview.dll
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\ts3websitepreview.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Debug\ts3websitepreview.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.60
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Which immediately changed to:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ts3websitepreview, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2016-06-15 06:39:54 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\ts3websitepreview.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  plugin.c
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Manifest:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LinkEmbedManifest:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  ts3websitepreview.vcxproj -> .\ts3websitepreview.dll
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\ts3websitepreview.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Debug\ts3websitepreview.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.71
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

After another build with **no changes to the code**.

But instead, it's still trying to load the DLL before the plugin even initializes, giving me a:

```
ts3client_win32.exe - System Error
The program can't start because libcurl.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I used the tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=msvc-160#specify-dlls-to-delay-load) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=msvc-160#load-all-imports-for-a-delay-loaded-dll) for delayed loading. I've also read the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606304/load-a-dll-from-another-directory-at-program-start), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173433/how-to-fix-dwmapi-dll-delay-load-dependency-under-winxp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999520/setdlldirectory-loadlibrary-inside-a-dll), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740670/dll-dependency-question-setdlldirectory) but none have solved my problem.

Comment: In Visual Studio, "Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Delay Loaded Dll" you should set "libcurl.dll;iconv.dll" etc.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I've already done that as you can see on line 10 of my first code example or line 21 or my actual code.

Comment: You have to change project properties, it's not a line of code. I can't see that anywhere in your question or the links. You have put too many links, I am not sure what you are referring too. Changing Project Properties option is all you need.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I put the Project Properties in a comment to easily show within the question that I had already set that Linker property. You can see my linker properties [here](https://github.com/NobleUplift/TeamSpeak3WebsitePreview/blob/master/ts3websitepreview/ts3websitepreview.vcxproj#L102).

Comment: It looks like you didn't add `*.dll` extension. VS should give you a linker warning. Make sure you set warning level to 4. By the way, I don't know what `__HrLoadAllImportsForDll` is for. I think it's used in connection with some other functions. You shouldn't need it. You might start another question if you that's important to your project (use the `WinAPI` tag in your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to include the **`"*.dll"`** extension. In linker option you must specify the following:

`libcurl.dll;libxml2.dll;zlib1.dll;iconv.dll;`

If you use `#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl")` then you don't have to specify it a second time in linker option.

`SetDllDirectory(L"./plugins/ts3websitepreview/");` should be sufficient. You don't need `__HrLoadAllImportsForDll`.

If you want to call DLL's `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` ahead of time, then use `LoadLibrary` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: Well that was probably my worst case of misreading the documentation ever. I'm getting `LINK : fatal error LNK1194: cannot delay-load 'libxml2.dll' due to import of data symbol '__imp__xmlFree'; link without /DELAYLOAD:libxml2.dll` but that might be another question altogether. Funny thing is if I comment it out, my DLL compiles and works fine... it will just memory leak.